# is it not possible to two htaccess codes at once?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website hosted on a free web hosting
it really messed my mind i put two codes in htaccess file one for 404 redirection
and other is for removing .html extension

in google chrome only one file is getting redirected on index.html [ i have total three.html files]
and in firefox no file is getting redirected its showing error and getting redirected on hosting website
when i put www.example.com/hello
it works fine
but when i put www.example.com/hello.html
it does not redirect on index page
same happens with if i type incorrect words it does not redirect on index.html
and when i remove second code (html extension remover) so 404 redirect code works fine
why?? what is the reason? is it not possible to add to 2 codes togather in htaccess file?

here is the code of htaccess--

```
    # Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{http://www.example.com/new} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /$1.html [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+)\.html\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ http://www.example.com/new/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You don't need to have the full url of the website in the RewriteCond. Checkout this guide on the topic. http://sicanstudios.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/